# Using .loc to categorize data and iterate over a dataframe using python to a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a CSV file with a list of items that I want to categorize based on a different category rather than color. The CSV file is:

```
     ITEM  PRICE  QUANTITY CATEGORY
0  Carrot      5        10   Orange
1  Potato      3         5    brown
2   Beans      2         6      red
3   Pizza      2         7      red
4   Salad      3         1    green
5  Burger      1         4    brown
6  Carrot      0         0   orange
7  Carrot      0         0   orange
8  Potato      0         0    brown
9   Beans      0         0      red
```

The code I wrote is:

```
import pandas as pd
path = 'C:\\Users\\[username]\\.spyder-py3\\TestFileCSV.csv

df = pd.read_csv(path)

if df.loc[index, 'ITEM'] == 'Carrot':
    df.loc[index, 'CATEGORY'] == 'VEGETABLE'
elif df.loc[index, 'ITEM'] == 'Beans':
    df.loc[index, 'CATEGORY'] == 'Legumes'
else:
    df.loc[index, 'CATEGORY'] == 'Check'
df.to_csv('TestFileCSV1.csv')
```

The result is I get a new file, TestFileCSV1, with the same exact dataframe as the original TestFileCSV. None of the categories are to vegetables or legumes.

Thank you!

EDIT: To clarify, I want to iterate over the list rather than assign the category one at a time. The actual dataset I want to categorize is thousands of items at a time. Thank you again!

Comment: Side note: Excel is *not* CSV. The extension of your file is .csv, not .xlsx, .xls, .xlsm, etc. Thus I have changed all Excel references and removed the Excel tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're using == for assignment instead of =.

You can use this to assign CATEGORY based on ITEM value:

```
df.loc[df['ITEM'] == 'Carrot', 'CATEGORY'] = 'VEGETABLE'
```

Comment: Use `df.loc[df['ITEM'].isin(['Potato', 'Carrot']), 'CATEGORY'] = 'VEGETABLE'` which changes category for all potatoes and carrots in df.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you so much! I'm still very new to dataframes and programming in general so I see what I did wrong. Thank you again! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['CATEGORY']= (df['ITEM'].apply(lambda x: 'VEGETABLE' if x=='Carrot' 
                                  else( 'Legumes' if x=='Beans' else 'Check')))

df
```

| index | ITEM | PRICE | QUANTITY | CATEGORY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Carrot | 5 | 10 | VEGETABLE |
| 1 | Potato | 3 | 5 | check |
| 2 | Beans | 2 | 6 | Legumes |
| 3 | Pizza | 2 | 7 | check |
| 4 | Salad | 3 | 1 | check |
| 5 | Burger | 1 | 4 | check |
| 6 | Carrot | 0 | 0 | VEGETABLE |
| 7 | Carrot | 0 | 0 | VEGETABLE |
| 8 | Potato | 0 | 0 | check |
| 9 | Beans | 0 | 0 | Legumes |

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit cleaner, I think

```py
# here we just map the values to the categories
def map(item):
  mapping = {'Carrot':"Vegetable",'Beans':"Legumes"}
  return map.get(item,"Check")


# apply, applies the map function to each value in x
df['CATEGORY'] = df.apply(lambda x: map(item = x['YEAR']), axis=1)
```